# Deploying rails after Getting Started guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I just finished following the getting started guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. In the guide I ran the development server on `http://localhost:3000`. Now I just moved the project folder to the directory of my website, but I cannot access the pages of the project by entering a URL. What steps do I need to do?

Comment: If I could recommend, get started learning Rails using: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Paul: Awesome that you were brave enough to ask this question. Not too many beginners feel comfortable asking basic questions. +1 for @SunnyJuneja's answer. RailsTutorial is the best resource for learning Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to host your Rails application on a server that has Rails installed. Then you will need to make sure that you start whatever web server you are running on that web server so that it can start accepting requests.

If you haven't already done it, I would suggest that you find a Rails-friendly web host that will handle the server configuration for you.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Do you have any recommendations on free Rails-friendly web hosts?

Comment: Heroku (http://heroku.com) will let you host very small applications for free.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your web server is Apache 2, you can use [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/).

See, Rails comes with its own little web server called Webrick, that isn't really suitable for production for various reasons. So when you run `rails server` you start *that* server.

You need to tell your server (e.g. Apache 2) what pages to process via your application, and how. And Passenger makes that very easy.

Answer (score 0):

The best guide to rails deployment is covered in chapter one of the rails tutorial book. It covers, source code version control as well as setting up the environment for deployment. Here is the link to chapter one: **http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#top**

Hope this helps.